# should I avoid bash -c, sh -c, and other shells' equivalents in my shell scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Consider the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
VAR='1 2 3'
bash -c "echo "\$$VAR""
eval "echo "\$$VAR""
bash -c "echo \"\$$VAR\""
eval "echo \"\$$VAR\""
```

Which outputs:

```
+ VAR='1 2 3'
+ bash -c 'echo $1' 2 3
3
+ eval 'echo $1' 2 3
++ echo 2 3
2 3
+ bash -c 'echo "$1 2 3"'
 2 3
+ eval 'echo "$1 2 3"'
++ echo ' 2 3'
 2 3
```

It seems both `eval` and `bash -c` interprets the codes the same way i.e `"echo "\$$VAR""` to `'echo $1' 2 3` and `"echo \"\$$VAR\""` to `'echo "$1 2 3"'`.

The only difference I seem to notice is that `bash -c` opens a subshell and thus varies the results from `eval`. For example, in

```
bash -c 'echo $1' 2 3
```

2 and 3 are the positional parameters for the subshell. On the other hand, in

```
eval 'echo $1' 2 3
```

they are just another arguments for `echo`.

**So my question is, is the `-c` option (`bash -c`, `sh -c` or other shells' equivalents) safe to use or is it evil like `eval`?**

Comment: Safe for what usage?

Comment: @Marki555 for command execution

Comment: They work very differently.

Comment: @amdixon can you explain a little?

Comment: I believe they are effectively functionally identical when passed identical input. You need to very carefully control/sanitize anything that might be run as a command. The main difference is the separate process spawned for `bash -c` as opposed to `eval` which is likely costlier and means variables can't "leak" back from the command.

Comment: In general, a great many of bash's extensions over POSIX sh are for the purpose of being able to reduce or eliminate `eval` calls -- see `printf -v` on the assignment end, `${!varname}` on the expansion end, bash 4.3 namevars, etc. It's vanishingly rare to still have a legitimate use case for `eval` with modern bash.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to be about avoiding running `bash -c` in general, but about running `bash -c` *from shell scripts*. There's nothing wrong with `bash -c` in the general case, where it's passed a static string of code, just like there's nothing wrong with running `bash somescript` when that script is static, handwritten, reviewed code; it's when either the argument to `-c` or the script is machine-generated without extreme care that either is dangerous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should avoid using `sh -c` and equivalents in your shell scripts, just as you avoid `eval`.

```
eval "$foo"
```

...is, when one boils it down, a security risk because it *treats data as code*, restarting the parsing process at the very beginning (thus, running expansions, redirections, etc). Moreover, because quoting contexts are considered in this process, content inside of the data being evaluated is able to escape quotes, terminate commands, and otherwise attempt to evade any efforts made at security.

```
sh -c "$foo"
```

does the same -- running expansions, redirections, and the like -- only in a completely new shell (not sharing non-exported variables or other state).

Both of these mean that content such as `$(rm -rf /)` is prone to being expanded unless great care is taken, rather than ensuring that -- as is generally the case -- *data will only ever be treated as data*, which is a foundational element of writing secure code.

---

Now, the happy thing here is that when you're using `bash` (or zsh, or ksh93) rather than `sh`, you **can** avoid using `eval` in almost all cases.

For instance:

```
value=$(eval "echo \$$varname")
```

...can be replaced with:

```
value=${!varname}
```

...and in bash,

```
eval "$varname="'$value'
```

...can be replaced with...

```
printf -v varname %s "$value"
```

...and so forth (with ksh93 and zsh having direct equivalents to the latter); more advanced formulations involving associative maps and the like are best addressed with the new bash 4.3 (and ksh93) namevar support.

---

Notably, `bash -c` **doesn't** replace `eval` effectively in most of the above examples, because it doesn't run in the same context: Changes made to shell state are thrown away when the child process exits; thus, not only does `bash -c` not buy safety, but it doesn't **work** as an `eval` replacement to start with.

Comment: quoting from  Etan Reisners' comment: `variables can't "leak" back from the command (in case of bash -c)`.. does that make `bash -c` any less evil than eval where both of them can be equally applied?

Comment: @Jahid, to that extent it's just an inefficient way of writing `(eval "$foo")` -- which also scopes state changes into a subshell, but does so without dropping locals first and with a `fork()` but no `exec()` and thus less performance penalty. However, in all legitimate uses of `eval` I can think of, dropping state changes is undesirable, because *the state changes are the whole point of using `eval`* -- if you don't need state changes, you can do something with less security risk a different way. This is why all the new shell features I talk about are ways of changing shell-local state.

Comment: @Jahid, ...after all, the risk is coming from `$(rm -rf .)`, which `sh -c` does nothing at all to protect against, not `var=value`, which a subshell's exit would discard.

Comment: @Jahid, ...the obvious exceptions are attacks based on setting a hostile PATH or LD_PRELOAD in the environment, but an attacker is more likely to enable those by editing dotfiles in-place, which will -- again -- persist after exit.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there is no reason to use `bash -c` from a bash shell. Using it will start a new process, which is expensive.

You can use eval, which doesn't start a new process. If you want a sub-shell (for example, to preserve the environment) you can use parentheses.

Normally, `bash -c` (or other shells with -c) is used to execute a command from another non-shell environment (or perhaps a DSL interpreted by a shell) where shell expansion of the arguments is required. In the old days, you might use it with `execvp` in a C program, for example. These days, there are usually ways of running a command using a shell in most environments.