# MySQL security and setup

Tags: mysql, bash

I am using MySQL on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The default MySQL `root` user has no password. To set it up non-interactively I do this:

```
bash -c 'mysql -uroot -e "create database `mydb`;"'
bash -c 'mysql -uroot -e "create user `myuser`@`localhost` identified by `myuser`;"'
bash -c 'mysql -uroot -e "grant all privileges on `myuser`.* to `myuser`@`localhost`"';
```

1. This script will be in a public repository. Is it safe, given that `root` and `myuser` has host=`localhost`?
2. Any improvements will be appreciated.

Comment: [`bash -c` is not secure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267791/should-i-avoid-bash-c-sh-c-and-other-shells-equivalents-in-my-shell-scripts)

Comment: @Jahid Ok, what about the mysql part? Any comments on that?

Comment: I don't see any other problems...

Comment: @Jahid What about question 1? Is it safe to have the password in a public repo?

Comment: `host=localhost` is not password, and in most cases it's the same, so I don't think it poses any security risk. But be sure to protect the password. And also, making username public is a security risk (not that much, but still I would avoid it If I could).

Comment: @Jahid `myuser` has password `myuser`. That's public, but it has `host=localhost` like `root`. So the password is public but it's restricted to localhost AFAIK. It's for an automated environment where **nothing can be managed manually**. What do you think about this?

Comment: Then it's definitely a security risk. password is the most sensitive information and the username is second to that. You can ignore `host=localhost`, it's usually the same for every db.

Comment: Well, no matter how easy and feasible it may seem it's a pretty bad idea to put this kind of sensitive info for public display. Better use private repo (which will be a lot more complex) or use some protected directory on the same server.

Comment: @Jahid A private repo is not an option, how would you secure mysql properly while setting it up with a noninteractive script?

Comment: The answer depends on various criteria: i) just what are you trying to do ii)where iii)how the server is configured iv)what type of server v)your access level etc... Unfortunately this type of question is off-topic in SO.